# Extract from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, url, hyperlink

i want to extract only Services.aspx from the link below

http : // localhost : 49169 / HirenSir / Services.aspx

using jQuery/javascript is admirable as then have to add a class to anchor tag containing this href parameter..

thanks

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific... Extract it from what? A string in a Perl script? A line in a text file? The two big questions: how are these URLs stored and what language are you looking to extract with?

Comment: Also, is there some pattern to what you're trying to do? What are your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in Javascript

```
var curPage = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

If your current location is Services.aspx

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Tv8Ay/)

**EDIT**

If you want to add a class to the anchor in this case try this

```
$('a[href$="Services.aspx"]').addClass('selected');
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Tv8Ay/1/)

Comment: I was just starting to work on a jdFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/jFw8F/2/ :P

Answer (score 1):

```
"http://localhost:49169/HirenSir/Services.aspx".split('/').pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions so far work... how about a regex?

```
var url = "http://localhost:49169/HirenSir/Services.aspx";

// returns array of matches, should only contain one element 
url.match("[^/]*$"); // ["Services.aspx"]
```

If you want it in a one-liner...

```
"http://localhost:49169/HirenSir/Services.aspx".match("[^/]*$")[0];
```